# ViroReact render issue in debug build android

Tags: android, react-native, viro-react

I am using [ViroARSampleApp](https://github.com/viromedia/ViroARSampleApp) code to demonstrates placing, rotating and dragging objects in AR. Everything is working fine when I run `react-native run-android --variant=arDebug` but when I detach data cable and run the app then the application is running fine but objects are not rendered.

I tried to make proper APK file and install to the device but facing the same issue. I tried these commands to make build `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`, `cd android`, `./gradlew assemblearDebug`. i also tried `./gradlew bundlearDebugJsAndAssets`.

I am new in react native and AR, kindly suggest me the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
./gradlew assembleGvrRelease
```